# Successful deploy, but I get the following error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, mern

I'm able to deploy but when I go to the website it says "CANNOT GET /". I'm getting this error when I do heroku logs: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html', I have no idea why. Here's my project structure:

[image]

Here's the server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const connectToDatabase = require("./db/connectToDatabase");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectToDatabase();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

// Routes
app.use("/vote", require("./routes/vote"));
app.use("/get-votes", require("./routes/get-votes"));
app.use("/create-teacher", require("./routes/create-teacher"));
app.use("/get-all-teachers", require("./routes/get-all-teachers"));

// Step 3
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "teachers-likelyhood",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cool rating web-app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engine": {
    "node": "12.13.0",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.8",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "Guillermo",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here's the .gitignore file:

```
node_modules
```

And lastly, here's the entire GitHub repo: https://github.com/guillevazq/MERN-Deployment-Help

Comment: Hi Guillermo, can you try `npm run build` with your client and tell us what happens. There is a possibility that the command doesn't work

Comment: Okay, just tried it, and it works. But the website still doesn't